# How to create a concatenated string from a List of Objects in VB.Net 3.5

Tags: vb.net, linq

I figure I should use 'Aggregate' but apparently I am getting it wrong

First I get a list of my Entity objects

```
    Dim employers As List(Of myEntity) = (New XXXX()).getZZZ(userName, userType)
```

Then I figured this would be a way to put all the names in a string

```
    Dim names as String = employers.Aggregate(Function(current, [next]) current.Name & " " & [next].Name)
```

but I get the error: "Cannot convert type 'lambda expression' to parameter type 'System.Func(Of myEntity, myEntity, myEntity......"

any clues?

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

`Dim names = String.Join(" ", employers.Select(Function(employer) employer.Name))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim names as String = employers.Aggregate("", Function(current, [next]) current & " " & [next].Name)
' Use this                                ^^                                  ^^
```

You might want to trim the string afterward, since it will start with a space.

Comment: Answer much appreciated.  it appears it can be done this way or @Phong's way.  which is better?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
Dim names as String = employers.Select(Function(emp) emp.Name ).Aggregate(Function(current, [next]) current & " " & [next])
```